# need to detect a ending path in the graph with minimilistic weight

Tags: algorithm

Would like to find the shortest weighted path from the node a to any node. The destination node is not given. One can visit any vertex many time.

if the path weight's should be less than Integer.MAX

what is the algorithm to proceed ..?? cant detect the algorithm itself.

i did try for travelling salesman problem but it doesn't match ; neither it match for Dijkstra ...

how to keep in memory all the paths is the major challenge here ..

Edit: Graph is not directed one and there are no negative wieghts.

references: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Is you graph directed or undirected? Can it have cycles? Are edge weights positive,  negative or can they be both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an undirected graph with no negative weights, it's possible to use [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm to find all-pairs shortest path with time complexity of O(V^3), where V is a number of vertices. The algorithm also allows an easy way to [reconstruct the all computed shortest paths](http://masc.cs.gmu.edu/wiki/FloydWarshall). It uses O(V^2) memory to store distances and additional information for reconstructing the path.

There are also some [other algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Undirected_graph) for solving this problem with better time complexity, but Floyd-Warshall is really easy to code and start with.

Answer (score 0):

> Would like to find the shortest weighted path from the node a to any
>   node.

I immediately think [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), because that's exactly what it does.

> how to keep in memory all the paths is the major challenge here ..

For each node in the graph, keep track of it's previous node that would result in the shortest path. Take a look at the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode), line 20.

To build the path, simply go backwards from the destination node until you reach the source node.